# How do you monitor incoming connections in Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2

I have a problem with an application  (VisualSVN) that is hosted on Amazons ec2.

when I try to connect to svn it refuses the connection.    What I want to know is if an actual connection attempt is coming through to the application and the application is actively refusing it.

so is there a way to see incoming connections?

Answer (score 2):

I found Microsofts Network Monitoring tool, it seems to do the job nicely

Comment: Link URL For MS Network Monitor: http://bit.ly/4i3CzV

Answer (score 2):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) is my tool of choice for such things. If you don't want to install it grab the portable version, which is handy to keep on your USB stick.